# How to start a windows service in Delphi for Windows 8

Tags: delphi

I need to Start a service using Delphi Windows application.It is working fine in Windows 7 but not working in Windows 8.1 .I have used the following code

```
function ServiceStart(sMachine,sService : string ) : boolean;
var
  schm,schs   : SC_Handle;
  ss     : TServiceStatus;
  psTemp : PChar;
  dwChkP : DWord;
begin
  ss.dwCurrentState := 0;
  schm := OpenSCManager(PChar(sMachine),Nil,SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if(schm > 0)then
  begin
    schs := OpenService(schm,PChar(sService),SERVICE_START or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if(schs > 0)then
    begin
      psTemp := Nil;
      if(StartService(schs,0,psTemp))then
      begin
        if(QueryServiceStatus(schs,ss))then
        begin
          while(SERVICE_RUNNING <> ss.dwCurrentState)do
          begin
            dwChkP := ss.dwCheckPoint;
            Sleep(ss.dwWaitHint);
            if(not QueryServiceStatus(schs,ss))then
            begin
              break;
            end;
            if(ss.dwCheckPoint < dwChkP)then
            begin
              break;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
      CloseServiceHandle(schs);
    end;
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);
  end;


  Result := SERVICE_RUNNING = ss.dwCurrentState;
end;


procedure TForm1.BBSerStatusClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServiceStart('','SERVTEST');
end;
```

Note: SERVTEST it is service application.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what happens. Which part fails? What is the error code? Tell us about your debugging. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a replacement for debugging.

Comment: I'm assuming that your program is running elevated

Comment: The above code is working fine for windows 7 but in windows 8 the code is only installing the service but not starting the service.

Comment: Did you read my comments? Not working conveys no meaning. At which point in the code do you encounter failure? What is the error code? Are you elevated?

Comment: Does you service even start if you go and try starting it from the Service management? You should check this first.

Comment: The documentation for `StartService` clearly says *If the function fails, the return value is 0. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.* I don't see a call to `GetLastError` to see why `StartService` didn't work. Clearly the **extended error information** it would provide would be useful here, don't you think?

Comment: I'm assuming that your two different test machines have different security policies configured - your Windows 7 machine apparently has looser security than your Windows 8.1 machine. Or in general, your application is running with elevated privileges in Windows 7 but not in Windows 8.1. If you were properly acquiring the error code, you would most likely learn that what you're trying to do requires elevation.

Comment: any error in EventViewer? did you install your app as services?

Answer (score 13):

I see that you are using code copied from [here](http://delphitipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2013/05/handling-windows-services-starting.html).

`if(schm > 0)then` and `if(schs > 0)then` should be changed to `if(schm <> 0)then` and `if(schs <> 0) then` instead.  The only failure value in this situation is 0 (some APIs use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead, but the SCM API does not). **Any** other value is a valid handle. Handles are not really integers (although Delphi declares them as such), so you should not treat them as integers. They are arbitrary values that are not meant to be interpreted, they are meant to be used as-is. If you do not get back an actual failure value (in this case, 0), then the call was successful regardless of the value actully returned.

The handling of `ss.dwCurrentState` is a little off, too. Instead of looping while `ss.dwCurrentState` is not `SERVICE_RUNNING`, loop while `ss.dwCurrentState` is `SERVICE_START_PENDING` instead.  If something goes wrong and the service never enters the `SERVICE_RUNNING` state, the loop will run forever, unless `QueryServiceStatus()` itself fails. And I would not suggest relying on `ss.dwCheckPoint` because not all services implement it correctly (in fact, Delphi's own `TService` does not - see [QC #1006 TService.ReportStatus reports incorrect CheckPoint](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=1006)).

Try something more like the following.  It differentiates between SCM API failures and Service start failures, but also does extra error checking to handle certain errors that are not actually fatal errors:

```
function ServiceStart(sMachine, sService : string) : Boolean;
var
  schm, schs : SC_HANDLE;
  ss : TServiceStatus;
begin
  schm := OpenSCManager(PChar(sMachine), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if (schm = 0) then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), SERVICE_START or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if (schs = 0) then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      // NOTE: if you use a version of Delphi that incorrectly declares
      // StartService() with a 'var' lpServiceArgVectors parameter, you
      // can't pass a nil value directly in the 3rd parameter, you would
      // have to pass it indirectly as either PPChar(nil)^ or PChar(nil^)
      if not StartService(schs, 0, nil) then
      begin
        Result := ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING = GetLastError();
        if not Result then RaiseLastOSError;
        Exit;
      end;
      repeat
        if not QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss) then
        begin
          if (ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE <> GetLastError()) then RaiseLastOSError;
          Result := False;
          Exit;
        end;
        if (SERVICE_START_PENDING <> ss.dwCurrentState) then Break;
        Sleep(ss.dwWaitHint);
      until False;
      Result := SERVICE_RUNNING = ss.dwCurrentState;
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(schs);
    end;
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);
  end;
end;
```

Or, here is a (modified) version of Microsoft's example, which also includes handling if the service is in `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` state before starting it (I removed timeout logic since it is based on `dwCheckPoint` handling):

[Starting a Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686315.aspx):

```
function ServiceStart(sMachine, sService : string) : Boolean;
var
  schSCManager,
  schService : SC_HANDLE;
  ssStatus : TServiceStatus;
begin
  // Get a handle to the SCM database.

  schSCManager := OpenSCManager(PChar(sMachine), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if (schSCManager = 0) then RaiseLastOSError; 
  try
    // Get a handle to the service.

    schService := OpenService(schSCManager, PChar(sService), SERVICE_START or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if (schService = 0) then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      // Check the status in case the service is not stopped.

      if not QueryServiceStatus(schService, ssStatus) then
      begin
        if (ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE <> GetLastError()) then RaiseLastOSError;
        ssStatus.dwCurrentState := SERVICE_STOPPED;
      end;

      // Check if the service is already running

      if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState <> SERVICE_STOPPED) and ssStatus.dwCurrentState <> SERVICE_STOP_PENDING) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Exit;
      end;

      // Wait for the service to stop before attempting to start it.

      while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING) do
      begin
        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is
        // one-tenth of the wait hint but not less than 1 second
        // and not more than 10 seconds.

        dwWaitTime := ssStatus.dwWaitHint div 10;

        if (dwWaitTime < 1000) then
          dwWaitTime := 1000
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000) then
          dwWaitTime := 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        // Check the status until the service is no longer stop pending.

        if not QueryServiceStatus(schService, ssStatus) then
        begin
          if (ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE <> GetLastError()) then RaiseLastOSError;
          Break;
        end;
      end;

      // Attempt to start the service.

      // NOTE: if you use a version of Delphi that incorrectly declares
      // StartService() with a 'var' lpServiceArgVectors parameter, you
      // can't pass a nil value directly in the 3rd parameter, you would
      // have to pass it indirectly as either PPChar(nil)^ or PChar(nil^)
      if not StartService(schService, 0, nil) then RaiseLastOSError;

      // Check the status until the service is no longer start pending.

      if not QueryServiceStatus(schService, ssStatus) then
      begin
        if (ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE <> GetLastError()) then RaiseLastOSError;
        ssStatus.dwCurrentState := SERVICE_STOPPED;
      end;

      while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING) do
      begin
        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is
        // one-tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no
        // more than 10 seconds.

        dwWaitTime := ssStatus.dwWaitHint div 10;

        if (dwWaitTime < 1000) then
          dwWaitTime := 1000
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000) then
          dwWaitTime := 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        // Check the status again.

        if not QueryServiceStatus(schService, ssStatus) then
        begin
          if (ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE <> GetLastError()) then RaiseLastOSError;
          ssStatus.dwCurrentState := SERVICE_STOPPED;
          Break;
        end;
      end;

      // Determine whether the service is running.

      Result := (ssStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING);
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
    end;
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is SC_HANDLE signed or unsigned?

Comment: In C, the Win32 API declares `SC_HANDLE` as either `struct SC_HANDLE__ *` or `void*` depending on whether `STRICT` is defined.  In Delphi, Win32 API handles, like `SC_HANDLE`, are declared as simply `THandle`, which is `Cardinal` or `NativeUInt` depending on platform.

Comment: In which case `>0` is semantically identical to `<>0`. I absolutely agree that `<>0` is better aesthetically, but that won't explain any behaviour changes.

Comment: Remy, if I could, I would have accepted your answer, but I cand only give you a +1. I tested your first `ServiceStart` routine and it's working perfectly. Thank you ! Do you think, if I start a new question, you could post an answer with how to stop the service ? I saw that in the link from where op copied his example is a Stop procedure too, but I don't trust that code if you said it has bugs. :)

Comment: @MarusNebunu: just use similar code as above, replacing the "start" pieces with corresponding "stop" pieces (`SERVICE_START` -> `SERVICE_STOP`, `StartService()` -> `ControlService(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)`, `SERVICE_START_PENDING` -> `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING`, `SERVICE_RUNNING` -> `SERVICE_STOPPED`, etc)